# What are dependencies required for cucumber-selenium-testng framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have started using cucumber framework with selenium-testng. Please, let me know the maven dependencies to start with. I am using Intellij IDE. One more thing, does cucumber support JDK11?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have the following dependencies added to your POM file:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <version>6.8</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

There shouldn't be an issue with running Cucumber with JDK11.

Comment: Thanks Davin, will implement the same and check.